# Is there a git command to beautify the output of git diff between two branches?

Tags: git, shell

I'm using the command below to compare two branches and write the diff to a file.

```
git diff origin/master...origin/child > diff.log
```

The output of above will be in raw format. How can I have it in a beautified format and written to a file?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56561749/edit) to include more information.  I personally use https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy .  **Edit** Please don't be discouraged if this question is closed because of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4.  You can always ask other questions as you get farther along in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Color codes are disabled when writing to a file since most tools and text editors will choke on them. Use `--color` to force them to be written.

```
git diff --color origin/master...origin/child > diff.log
```

To view the file use `less -R` or `cat`.

```
less -R diff.log
cat diff.log
```

Comment: Thanks John. That helps. And also is there a way to filter certain details from the difference and write to the file?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with your requirements. Put everything you want in one place.